# Trouble with frame around figure

Tags: graphics, floats

I'm currently attempting to place a frame around a figure in an `Elsevier` template. My figure contains 4 images in a 2 by 2 grid. When I try to use the command `\fbox`, all the images bunch up and the formatting is ruined.

Is there a way to fix this problem with minimal pain? Below is part of my code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\fbox{ 
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ews1}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ews3}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ews2}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ews4}
     }
\label{f1}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `\label` must be placed **after** `\caption`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use a `\parbox{...}` inside of the `\fbox{...}` and leave an empty line after two of the `\includegraphics` statements.

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering

\fbox{ %
\parbox{0.7\textwidth}{%
 \centering

\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ente}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ente}

\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ente}
\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{ente}
}
}
\caption{}
\label{f1}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Christian Hupfer, that does it. I'll accept the answer as soon as SE lets me.

Comment: @JohnWayne360: Thanks. Happy TeXing!